# Unitary Transformations for States with Same Entanglement

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises, unitarity

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
I know this has been asked before in another context ([How to construct local unitary transformations mapping a pure state to another with the same entanglement?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20684/how-to-construct-local-unitary-transformations-mapping-a-pure-state-to-another-w)), but a similar issue dealing with the same paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9811053.pdf) caused me to ask this question.

If $\Ket{\psi'} \sim \Ket{\psi''}$, then $\Ket{\psi''} = (U_A\otimes U_B) \Ket{\psi'}$ for some local unitary transformations $U_A$ and $U_B$. Here, $\Ket{x} \sim \Ket{y}$ iff $\rho_x$ and $\rho_y$ have the same spectrum of eigenvalues.

The question is: How does one construct local unitary transforms to map the states $\Ket{\psi'''_2} \rightarrow \Ket{\psi'''_1}$, and $\Ket{\psi'''_1} \rightarrow \Ket{\psi^4}$, where:

$$ 
\Ket{\psi'''_1} =  \cos(\delta)\Ket{00} + \sin(\delta)\Ket{1} \big[ \cos(\gamma)\Ket{0} + \sin(\gamma)\Ket{1} \big] \\
\Ket{\psi'''_2} =  \sin(\delta)\Ket{00} + \cos(\delta)\Ket{1} \big[ \cos(\gamma)\Ket{0} + \sin(\gamma)\Ket{1} \big] \\
\Ket{\psi^4} = \sqrt{\lambda_+} \Ket{00} + \sqrt{\lambda_-} \Ket{11} \\
$$

Note that $\lambda_{\pm} = \big(1\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\delta)\sin^2(\gamma)}\big)/2$, and the Schmidt coefficients of all states are the same. I have tried solving this problem using both Mathematica and by hand (following the method of [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/20687/16667)), but both were yet unfruitful. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: Answer can be found [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/20727/16667)**

Comment: I don't understand the difference between this and the linked question

Comment: The issue I was having was that the expressions obtained using that method were quite unwieldy, and I wasn't able to obtain a closed-form analytical solution given the conditions of orthonormality.

Comment: There are many things you can try: trigonometry, numerics, guessing, a symbolic calculation package other than Mathematica, doing some special cases first (e.g. $\gamma=0$) and then you can always resort to reshaping the states from $4\times 1$ matrices to $2\times 2$ matrices to transform the task of finding the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) into the task of finding the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Hope this helps! :-)